# Blank page in prod with Symfony 6.2.*

Tags: symfony, redirect

With Syfmony 6.2.7 and PHP 8.2, a controller method displays a blank page without error in prod mod, but not locally on my computer.

Hi guys,

I'm working on a Symfony project in version 6.2.7, and I'm encountering a strange problem.

There is a link that passes "route" and "route_params" parameters to a controller method.
This method handles the acceptance of cookies and then redirects.
On my computer, whether in dev mode or prod mode, it works very well.

In server side prod mode when the link is clicked, the url of the method is displayed in the browser but the page is white and nothing happens (see screenshot below).
I tried to use the dev mode on the server side, and there is no error (the web_profiler does not appear on the white page).

Does anyone have an idea? :)

**Screenshot :**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovLd3.png)

**Link in HTML/Twig :**

```
<a href="{{ path('cookie_banner_accept_cookies', {'route' : app.request.attributes.get('_route'), 'route_params' : app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')}) }}" class="btn btn-success ms-3">{{ 'cookiesConsent.accept'|trans }}</a>
```

**Controller method :**

```
    /**
     * @Route("{_locale}/accept_cookies", name="cookie_banner_accept_cookies", requirements={"_locale"="%locales_requirements%"})
     */
    public function acceptCookies(Request $request)
    {
        $route = $request->query->get('route');

        /**@var array */
        $route_params = $request->query->get('_route_params');

        $cookieConsent = Cookie::create('vertice_cookies_consent', 'accepted', strtotime('now + ' . '365 days'));
        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->setCookie($cookieConsent);
        $response->send();

        return $this->redirectToRoute($route, [
            'route_params' => $route_params
        ]);
    }
```

The other redirections of the website in prod mode work fine.
The server side PHP version is 8.2, and the symfony/apache-pack bundle is well installed in the project.

Thanks in advance.

Thibaut.

Comment: The next step is to check your server logs.

Comment: Thanks @Cerad .
There are errors to start the session. Apart from that I don't see anything wrong

Comment: Hmmm.  Sending a response and then doing a redirect seems a bit problematical.

Comment: @Cerad I've thought about that too, but haven't tested it in production yet. I'll test it tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: @Cerad Ok, I am now using the RedirectResponse component and it seems to work well for almost everything.

It doesn't work when there is a url parameter, like a slug.
I can't get that parameter on the controller side even though I pass it in well from Twig. I just get the `_local` parameter but not the `slug` of the current route in the Request.


`<a href="{{ path('cookie_banner_accept_cookies', {'route' : app.current_route, 'route_params' : app.current_route_parameters }) }}" class="btn btn-success ms-3">{{ 'cookiesConsent.accept'|trans }}</a>`

Comment: I don't see anything in your posted code that uses a slug.  Is it a completely different question?

Comment: It's for generate an url with slug if the current route have slug param. I solved the problem by retrieving the route parameter array from the Request and passing it to the `generateUrl()` method. Thanks for your help @Cerad

Comment: @Fonctionnaire if you've a solution don't add it inside the question, but add in the answer section instead.

Comment: @gp_sflover Thanks for the tip, I'm going to do that.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved**

You have to use the `RedirectResponse` class and `generateUrl()` method instead of the `Response` class and `redirectTorRoute()`.

To retrieve the parameters of the current route, use `app.current_route_parameters` in the Twig path, retrieve them from the controller with `$request->query->all()` and pass the retrieved array as the second parameter of the `generateUrl()` method.

**Controller :**

```
/**
 * @Route("{_locale}/accept_cookies", name="cookie_banner_accept_cookies", requirements={"_locale"="%locales_requirements%"})
 */
public function acceptCookies(Request $request): Response
{
    /** @var array{route: string, route_params: array<string, string>} $query*/
    $query = $request->query->all();

    $cookieConsent = Cookie::create('vertice_cookies_consent', 'accepted', strtotime('now + ' . '365 days'));

    $url = $this->generateUrl($query['route'], $query['route_params']);

    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
    $response->headers->setCookie($cookieConsent);
    $response->send();

    return $response;
}
```

**Twig :**

```
<a href="{{ path('cookie_banner_accept_cookies', {'route' : app.current_route, 'route_params' : app.current_route_parameters }) }}" class="btn btn-success ms-3">{{ 'cookiesConsent.accept'|trans }}</a>
```